# How to use grep to search for strings in a loop

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames.

```
 #df1 dimensions [100,1]  
    item 
   "Like to cook"
   "Enjoy football"
    .............
   "Love to run"

 #df2 dimensions [3,1]
    item
   "Like to cook"
   "Enjoy football"
   "Love to run"
```

In df1 and df2, a single variable is sting. I am trying to use grep to take every element of df2, find respective matche in df1, and output a vector of row positions of where these matches are in df1. So the output would look something like [1]  1 2 100

```
   I tired the following, but for some reason I get the following  
   result:
```

`Integer(0)`.

I would be grateful for your help please.

```
 result = NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
 result = grep(df2[,1], df1)
 }
 print(result)
```

Comment: Does this work? `result = NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
 result = grep(df2[i,1], df1)
 }
 print(result)`

Comment: Do you get an error or just `integer(0)`?

Comment: unfortunately not. The output is [1] 1 which is incorrect.

Comment: @NelsonGon just output: integer(0)

Comment: That's not an error. That simply means no match was found.

Comment: @NelsonGon when I used grep to search item by item, I find correct match and row position. But when I try a loop, the output is incorrect. The motivation to use a loop is that I have a lot of items to search and doing that manually is inefficient

Comment: It seems you're just merging. What do you want to do?

Comment: I guess you need `match`: `set.seed(42); x <- LETTERS[sample(1:26, 3)];
match(x, LETTERS)`

Comment: @NelsonGon If I merge, I need to ensure that matching items end up beside each other. But I would still need the output as to the exact location of matched rows after merger. I tried all sorts of merger commands but failed to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your loop:

```
result = df
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  result[i,] = grep(df2[i,], df[,1])

}
result
         item
1           1
2           2
3           4
4 Love to run
```

Using a `character` vector:

```
result = character()
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  result[i] = grep(df2[i,], df[,1])

}
result
```

No loops:

```
 match(df2$item,df$item)
[1] 1 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
 result <- which(df1$a %in% df2$a)



        df1 <- data.frame(a = c("Like to cook", "Enjoy football", rep("any", 97),"Love to run"))
        df2 <- data.frame(a = c("Like to cook", "Enjoy football", "Love to run"))
```